# Is there anyway we can use the Left Join in the SOLR?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am working on converting RDBMS query to SOLR. Here i am facing issue with Left Outer join. Is SOLR support Left outer Join? If yes, what are ways i can implement it. Thanks

Here is the table which i am try to convert into SOLR:

```
SELECT * FROM abc cg LEFT OUTER JOIN xyz ac 
ON cg.S_ID = ac.CHILD_ID INNER JOIN abc cg1 ON cg1.S_ID = ac.PRENT_ID;
```

Comment: Solr doesn't really support joins (in the RDBMS sense), but exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: Here is the table which i am try to convert into SOLR:       SELECT * FROM  abc cg
LEFT OUTER JOIN xyz ac ON cg.S_ID = ac.CHILD_ID
INNER JOIN abc cg1 ON cg1.S_ID = ac.PRENT_ID;

Comment: You should probably do that join when you're generating and inserting your documents, so that all the content is kept in a single document instead.

Answer (score 1):

Solr implements some joins (see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join), but you should try to avoid them if you can if you are trying to get high performance querying out of SOLR (https://lucidworks.com/blog/2012/06/20/solr-and-joins/)

Comment: Thanks. I had already gone through this link but not get what i am looking for.

Comment: Here is the table which i am trying to convert into SOLR: SELECT * FROM abc cg LEFT OUTER JOIN xyz ac ON cg.S_ID = ac.CHILD_ID INNER JOIN abc cg1 ON cg1.S_ID = ac.PRENT_ID;. Please see